# Search Boolean Field in Boostrap-Table

Tags: javascript, spring, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I use [Bootstrap-Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) to create my table on my `Spring` WebApp.

I have a question about search filters.
In one of my tables I want to search a boolean field, but I would like to search for it on the basis of a label I assign.

To clarify I attach my code:

```
  <c:url value="/myurl/" var="Url" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
    function booleanFormatter(value) {
        if(value){
            return '<span class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green;"></span>';
        }else{
            return '<span class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></span>';    
        }
    };

    $(function() {
        $("#tableCli").on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
            window.location= "${Url}"+row.id;
        });
    });

  ]]>
</script>

<div class="container">
    <table data-toggle="table" 
    data-url="${Url}listgrid"
    data-page-size="30"
    data-pagination="true" 
    data-search="true" 
    data-show-columns="true" 
    data-classes="table table-hover" 
    data-striped="true" id="tableCli"
    data-show-refresh="true" 
    data-sort-name="inUso"
    data-sort-order="desc">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-sortable="true" data-field="ragioneSociale">${labelNomeCliente}</th>
                <th data-field="piva" data-sortable="true">${labelPIva}</th>
                <th data-field="comune" data-sortable="true">${labelComune}</th>
                <th data-field="codiceIdMacchine" data-sortable="true">${labelCodifica}</th>
                <th data-field="enable" data-formatter="booleanFormatter" data-sortable="true">${labelEnable}</th>
                <th data-field="foreign" data-formatter="booleanFormatter" data-sortable="true">${labelEstero}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

The fields `Enable` and `Foreign`  are `Boolean`, and for my users I want that if search with tips "Enable" the result is the list of enabled customer, same thing for the field "Foreign".

I try to search in link documentation but I don't see nothing.
Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you can try to add two new columns for these two bool fields but without any formatting and also set the style as display none.

Comment: @palaѕн thanks for the suggestion. Adding the value `data-visible="false"` instead of `style=display:none;` and run.